# to understand return correctly

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I´m learning java and try to write the following method.

Compare two arrays of char, if the array b is completly included in array a.

So this is my code.

```
public static boolean containsPattern(char[] chars ,char[] pattern) { 

    boolean tellMe= true;

    for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<pattern.length;j++) {

            if(chars[i]==pattern[j]) {
                for(int k=0;k<pattern.length;k++) {
                    if(chars[i]==pattern[k])
                         return tellMe;
                }
            } else 
                return tellMe = false;                      
        }       
    }
    return tellMe;
}
```

I want it to return me true if the condition `chars[i]==pattern[k]` is true for all elements of pattern. But the return breaks up with the first true.

How can I write it, that it just returns true if all `chars[i]==pattern[k]` is true?

Best regards
molt

Comment: `return tellMe=false` does not do what you think it does. You probably meant `==`.

Comment: you could just reverse the problem if one doesn't match then it's ovbiously false

Comment: so obvious mistakes...thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are trying to do.

```
public static boolean containsPattern(char[] chars, char[] pattern) {
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(chars[i] + " " + pattern[i]);
        if(chars[i] != pattern[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

so `containsPattern(new char[]{'a', 'c'}, new char[]{'a', 'c'});` is true
but `containsPattern(new char[]{'a', 'c'}, new char[]{'a', 'b'});` is false